# Add some paramaters to url as directory but point to original url with query paramaters

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I want that if somebody hits this url:

```
https://sk.carpul.eu/search?t=0&fp=Bratislava&fla=48.1486&fln=17.1077&tp=Zvolen&tla=48.5762&tln=19.1371&sdate=&stime=&p=1&qh=4b9873ddfb
```

It will have nice places in url and search rename to spolujazda as:

```
https://sk.carpul.eu/spolujazda/Bratislava/Zvolen/?t=0&fp=Bratislava&fla=48.1486&fln=17.1077&tp=Zvolen&tla=48.5762&tln=19.1371&sdate=&stime=&p=1&qh=4b9873ddfb
```

But still server will point to:

```
https://sk.carpul.eu/search?t=0&fp=Bratislava&fla=48.1486&fln=17.1077&tp=Zvolen&tla=48.5762&tln=19.1371&sdate=&stime=&p=1&qh=4b9873ddfb
```

I tried in htaccess:

```
# check if the actual request if for "this1"
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /search\.php\?fp=([^&]+)&tp=([^&\ ]+)
# redirect to "this2"
RewriteRule ^ spolujazda/%1/%2/? [R=301,L,NE]

# now rewrite "this2" back to "this1"
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?search/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /search.php?fp=$1&tp=$2 [L,QSA]
```

But not working.

For .php removal I have this in the beginning of htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On


## hide .php extension
# To internally forward /dir/file to /dir/file.php
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /$1.php [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Your `search` URL doesn't have `.php` and why do you have `spolujazda/search` in target of rule?

Comment: I already applied rule to remove php from file names

Comment: spolujazda/search is mistake but event that not working

Comment: I added beginning part to remove php

Comment: Your URL has many query parameters between `fp` and `tp` and afterwards also

Comment: I know but I want only fp and tp appear as folder.  Number of paramaters cannot be problem.

Comment: And you still want to keep `fp=` and `tp=` after redirect as shown?

Comment: It is not mandatory but I would like to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use these rules in your site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

# check if the actual request if for "this1"
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /search(?:\.php)?\?(?:.*&)?fp=([^&]+).*&tp=([^&\s]+) [NC]
# redirect to "this2"
RewriteRule ^ /spolujazda/%1/%2/ [R=301,L,NE]

# now rewrite "this2" back to "this1"
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?(?:spolujazda|search)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /search.php?fp=$1&tp=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: thanks It looks it works but it totally breaks my css rules on page

Comment: It doesn't break any rules. You are most likely using relative links in your css and may need to add add this just below `<head>` section of your page's HTML: `<base href="/" />`